# Salt concentration differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> There is a 100 liter container full with a 10 kg salt solution. There
> is a 10% salt solution going into the container with 5liter/min speed,
> which dissolves instantly with the solution in the container. The
> solution exits the container at the bottom with the same speed. How
> much salt will there be in the container after 2 hours?

**My solution goes like:**
Let $x(t)$ be the salts amount in the tank after *t* time 
$x(0) = 10 (kg)$

$t \Rightarrow t+Δt$
$x(t+Δt)-x(t) =$ "The amount that flows in - The amount that flows out"

**Flows in:** 
5l/min of 10% salt solution $\Rightarrow$ 0.5 kg of salt/min

**Flows out:**
$5l/min -> \frac{5}{100}$x(*t*) = $\frac{x(t)}{20}$
in $Δt$ minutes $Δt$ $\times$ $5l$ $\Rightarrow  \frac{Δt \times x(t)}{20}$

**So the whole equation looks like this:**
${x(t+Δt)-x(t)} = 0.5-\frac{Δt \times x(t)}{20}$

My question really is if this thought process for solving this is good, or if not where have I made a mistake? Also sorry for the terrible translation of the exercise.

Comment: If you start with a ten percent solution and a ten percent solution enters at the same speed as a ten percent solution exits, wouldn't the solution stay at ten percent?

Comment: @JohnDouma I agree: from the wording of the question it seems the concentration of salt remains constant, so there may be something wrong with the question statement.

Comment: I think it's not since it like dissolves instantly, and more salt is coming in than it is exiting, since it dissolves instantly. At least that's my interpretation of the problem is. However it may very well be wrong.

Comment: @LakatosMárk If you solve the differential equation given by David below you get $x=10-Ae^{\frac{-t}{20}}$ where $A$ is a constant. Evaluating $x(0)$ gives $A=0$ so the solution is $x=10$ which means the amount of salt stays constant. Intuitively, as a drop of water enters, a drop of water leaves and each drop contains the same amount of salt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “Flows In” expression should be $$0.5\Delta t$$
Therefore, the equation should be $$x(t+\Delta t)-x(t)=0.5\Delta t-\frac{\Delta t\times x(t)}{20}$$

Now divide by $\Delta t$ and let $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$

So your differential equation is $$\frac{dx}{dt}=0.5-\frac{x}{20}$$

Can you solve this?

Comment: I think so yeah.  The final result I got is `x(t) =d*e^(9t/20)` where d is + or - C. Also if I cross reference it to X(0) which is 10 I get that C = 10